# What is md-component-id?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

The [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSidenav) on the `md-sidenav` directive states:

> md-component-id - string - componentId to use with $mdSidenav service.

- What is componentId?
- Which values are available besides the obvious `left` and `right` (e.g., in [Fuse template](http://fuse-angular-material.withinpixels.com/mail/inbox), a value of `main-sidenav` is used)?
- Is it optional?
- How does it affect the sidebar?

Comment: did my answer solve the question? If not I will be glad to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component id is an attribute really like an ID, if you have more then one ID is really important to create some for your component, so you can call things like: `$mdSidenav(navID)` in your angular code, is not just left or right the ids you can put, I recommend you put a name that you can know which component you whant to call on your Controller or service. See this codepen to clarify: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvegxZ